# How to get the messages in a conversation view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a messages table which was working fine with inbox, sent_items and archive etc.,

But the client wants the messages to be in the conversation view.

Here is my messages table structure,

```
Field             Type  
id                int(11) 
from_fb_uid       varchar(45)
to_fb_uid         varchar(45)
message_body      text
sent_datetime     datetime
read_status       tinyint(1)
archived          tinyint(1)
```

First i need to display the latest(only message for each conversation based on the user viewing) conversation message .

When i click the conversation message, i need to display all the messages as a conversation view.

Once i know the receive & sender in a conversation , i use the following query to get the list of messages based on the sent_time (to keep the conversation view)..

```
SELECT * FROM `user_message` 
WHERE 
(from_fb_uid='100002638144690' and to_fb_uid='100002564538409') 
or 
(from_fb_uid='100002564538409' and to_fb_uid ='100002638144690') 
order by 
sent_datetime desc
```

But i dont know how to get the list of new conversations and list the latest message in the conversation thread...

how to do this?

### Update:

I've modified the table structure with two entities as

```
 user_conversation table

    Field                          Type     

    conversation_id                int(11)
    sender_id_user                 int(11)
    sender_fb_uid                  varchar(45)
    receiver_id_user               int(11)
    receiver_fb_uid                varchar(45)
    sender_archive_status          tinyint(1)
    receiver_archive_status        tinyint(1)
    last_updated                   timestamp

 user_message table

    Field             Type  

    id                int(11) 
    from_fb_uid       varchar(45)
    to_fb_uid         varchar(45)
    message_body      text
    sent_datetime     datetime
    read_status       tinyint(1)
    archived          tinyint(1)
```

Now how can list the latest message for a user with the sender?

Comment: Create another entity `conversation` in db and things will be much easier to do (and actually more efficient)

Comment: In the absence of a `conversation` entity that @zerkms is speaking about, what should be considered a *conversation* in your schema/environment? Is it all the messages ever sent between two particular users?

Comment: @Andriy yes..That is what i'm talking about.. If conversation entity should be added, then what could be the best table structure for both conversation & messages.. ?

Comment: @Vijay: Good question. And I mean, good *question*. :) In terms of querying data, I think it would be more convenient to have a common identifier, something along the lines of what Zerkms is suggesting. But from the application's point of view, linking to a previous message (the one that the user is presently replying to) seems to me more natural and, possibly, easier to implement. So, in the end, I might consider implementing a sort of mixture of both. I'm not sure if it has to be a separate table or just additional column(s) in `user_message`. That might require additional considerations.

Comment: @zerkms I've updated my question with updated table structure, can you shed some light on that?

Comment: @AndriyM I've updated my question with updated table structure, can you shed some light on that?

Comment: Not sure I can see how your schema is working. In any event, your question seems to be shifting from "How to get the messages in a conversation view?" to something like "How can I incorporate a conversation entity into my user/message schema?". I thought if you were interested in the latter, you would be asking a new question rather than messing up with this one.

Comment: I'd like to point out that I gave you merely my *suggestions* but someone else might share their actual *experience* with you on the topic – that is, *if* there was an appropriate question about that. In my opinion, your original question still make some sense without introducing conversations as entities, so maybe you should leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to find the latest 10 conversations.  You'd have to join back to find the `message_body` for the latest message.

```
select  um.from_fb_uid
,       um.to_fb_uid
,       um.message_body 
from    user_message um
join    (
        select  from_fb_uid
        ,       to_fb_uid
        ,       max(sent_datetime) as max_dt
        from    user_message um2
        group by
                from_fb_uid
        ,       to_fb_uid
        order by
                max(sent_datetime) desc
        limit   10
        ) as filter
on      filter.from_fb_uid = um. from_fb_uid
        and filter.to_fb_uid = um. to_fb_uid
        and filter.max_dt = um.sent_datetime
```

Comment: I tried this, this query lists all the individual messages based on the sentime but not the latest one( most recently sent b/w two users) for each conversation.

Comment: It should find the latest conversations.  Try running the subquery aliased to `filter`; does that work?

Comment: I've updated my question with updated table structure, can you shed some light on that?